# Creating whole new view based on current user's group sharepoint 2013

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to generate a view based on the current user's group name. Group Name I am gathering from the custom list.

My question is how to apply the gathered group name to 'Group Name' column as a view parameter.

[image: screenshot]

**The only solution I figured:**

I have created a view with a parameter.

I have added an HTML Form Web Part into the same page and connected it to the list view (sending the value to the parameter via web part connection). Then with a `window.onload` function I gather the current user's group name and pass this value via Form Postback function. But since the Postback function triggers full page reload, it falls into the endless loop of form submission > page reload.

Another way I have tried is attaching a click event listener to the BY MY GROUPS tab and it works perfectly, but the only disadvantage is that the page reloads each time user clicks on this tab, which I would like to avoid.

So the solution that I need is a way to post the form without a page reload.

Another option suggested here is to use CSR (client side rendering), but that has its own problems:

1. This code does not work as it is supposed to. In the console it shows me correct items, but the view appears untouchable.
2. Even if it worked, the other column values are still viewable in the column filter, as in this screenshot: [image: screenshot]

So, it seems that CSR just hides items from the view (and they are still available). In other words its behavior is different from, for example, a CAML query.

Or am I getting it wrong and there's something wrong with my code?

Below you can find my CSR code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
(function() {
    function listPreRender(renderCtx) {
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function() {
            var currUserID = _spPageContextInfo.userId;
            var cx = new SP.ClientContext('/sites/support');
            var list = cx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Group Members');
            var items = list.getItems(SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery());
            cx.load(items, 'Include(_x006e_x50,DepID)');
            cx.executeQueryAsync(
                function() {
                    var i = items.get_count();
                    while (i--) {
                        var item = items.getItemAtIndex(i);
                        var userID = item.get_item('_x006e_x50').get_lookupId();
                        var group = item.get_item('DepID').get_lookupValue();
                        if (currUserID === userID) {
                            var rows = renderCtx.ListData.Row;
                            var customView = [];
                            var i = rows.length;
                            while (i--) {
                                var show = rows[i]['Group_x0020_Name'] === group;
                                if (show) {
                                    customView.push(rows[i]);
                                }
                            }
                            renderCtx.ListData.Row = customView;
                            renderCtx.ListData.LastRow = customView.length;
                            console.log(JSON.stringify(renderCtx.ListData.Row));
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                },
                function() {
                    alert('Something went wrong. Please contact developer')
                }
            );
        });
    }
    function registerListRenderer() {
        var context = {};
        context.Templates = {};
        context.OnPreRender = listPreRender;
        SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(context);
    }
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(registerListRenderer, 'clienttemplates.js');
})();
</script>
```

Comment: Is the Group Name column a people-picker field or just a single line of text field?

Comment: It is a single line of text (custom naming convention (different from original) for group (department) names). Thanks for edit btw

Comment: Please, close topic, since it seems impossible to do